# How to put custom space between digits of a phone number in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, string

I need to show Phone number in formatted number like this: +91 8346438438 to +91 8346 4384 38.
I am using following code to implement this functionality :

```
  extension String {
    
      func separate(every stride: Int = 4, with separator: Character = " ") -> String {
          return String(enumerated().map { $0 > 0 && $0 % stride == 0 ? [separator, $1] : [$1]}.joined())
      }
  }
```

and i am using this extension for a string like this:

```
text?.separate(every: 2, with: " ")
```

But i am able to get  spaces only after each 2 digit, whereas i want to put space in custom manner like firstly after 3 digits and then after 4 digits.
How can i change the extension to implement this?

Comment: There seems to be some frameworks for that, google "swift format phone number"

Comment: You should deal with the country code separately, format the number and join them with a space. Not every country code has 2 digits

Comment: BTW not related to your question but your extension can simply use `flatMap` instead of `map` and `join`. `.init(enumerated().flatMap { $0 > 0 && $0 % stride == 0 ? [separator, $1] : [$1]})`

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus i will do that.i have another doubt ,when i am using this extension for textfield like this: textfield.text?.separate(every :2 ,with : " ") .but i am not getting spaces in the textfield while entering number.while it works fine with a simple string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get rid of the spaces in your original string. If what you really want is to define a place to start inserting the character separator you can simply check if the offset is equal to the start offset or the offset truncating remainder dividing by stride is equal to the start instead of zero.

```
extension Bool {
    var negated: Bool { !self }
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func separate(every stride: Int = 4, from start: Int = 0, with separator: Character = " ") -> String {
        .init(enumerated().flatMap { $0 != 0 && ($0 == start || $0 % stride == start) ? [separator, $1] : [$1]})
    }
}
```

---

```
"+91 8346438438".filter(\.isWhitespace.negated)
    .separate(every: 4, from: 3, with: " ")
```

---

edit/update:

```
class CustomField: UITextField {
    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    @objc func editingChanged() {
        text?.removeAll{ !("0"..."9" ~= $0 || $0 == "+") }
        text?.insert(separator: " ", from: 3, every: 4)
        print(text ?? "") 
    }

}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func insert<S: StringProtocol>(separator: S, from start: Int = 0, every n: Int) {
        var distance = count
        for index in indices.dropFirst(start).reversed() {
            distance -= 1
            guard distance % n == start && index != startIndex else { continue }
            insert(contentsOf: separator, at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
var text = "+91 8346438438"
text.removeAll(where: \.isWhitespace)
text.insert(separator: " ", from: 3, every: 4)
print(text)  // +91 8346 4384 38
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer.it is working perfectly in case of a separate string ,but when i  use it for textfield using :   self.numberTextField.text!.filter(\.isWhitespace.negated)
        .separate(every: 4, from: 3, with: " ") .i am not getting space while entering digits.please help me regarding this.

Comment: I am using in that way as well: ```self.numberTextField.text! = self.numberTextField.text!.filter(\.isWhitespace.negated)
        .separate(every: 4, from: 3, with: " ")``` .still not working

Comment: @satyamkumar it is not working is too vague. Are you doing this inside editingChanged? I mean are you using a method target on [`UIControl.Event.editingChanged`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/event/1618241-editingchanged)?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning in clear.basically i am using this within following condition: ```if(self.numberTextField.isEditing)
        {
             self.numberTextField.text = self.numberTextField.text?.separate(every: 2, with: " ")
        }```.how should i use UIControl.Event.editingChanged for method target?please suggest me

Comment: if you don't add in which context your code is I wont be able to help you. Do you know how to change the textfield on editing changed?

Comment: Currently i am using isEditing method of textField,but not getiing result.please suggest me some other way to change the text field on editing changed as i am beginner to swift.

Comment: @satyamkumar check my last edit. Do you know how to use a subclass of UITextField?